# Is there any dedicated, academic channel i could use to establish contact with other universities on an international scale?

Tags: research-process, email

I'm a doctoral student at the fine arts faculty of the University of the Basque Country (UPV/EHU), Spain (European Union), in the Art and Technology department, and i have a question about the elaboration of my thesis that you might be able to help me with.

To acquire a sizable part of the information needed to conduct my research, i need to establish contact with forty two universities spread across the globe, mostly to conduct interviews in text, audio and video formats about culture, art, and technology.

I already asked both my thesis directors and faculty administrators about what the best way to contact this universities would be, but they have been unable to offer me a proper answer so far. I could contact them with my personal university email, but i still think that it would be more appropriate to do so trough a dedicated channel, but i wonder about the existence of a dedicated, international channel that i could use to do so in a more formal way.

To recap, my question would be as follows:

- As a doctoral student and citizen of the European Union, is there any dedicated, preferably free of charge, academic channel i could use to establish contact with other universities on an international scale?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Martin

Comment: What would be the problem with using your university e-mail address?

Comment: Google is your friend. Maybe your only friend.

Comment: Yes. It is called your professional email.

Comment: Who exactly do you want to contact/interview in the universities? It looks like you need a more specific target

Comment: Universities run on email. As a university student, you probably have a university email address? Use that. But also, get advice from your thesis advisor(s) on who to contact; just writing to universities probably won't get yhou far.

Comment: Are you asking whether there is something like a "Red Phone" that allows calling other universities from your university, with a guarantee that the other side will actually pick up and deal with your request?

Comment: What do you mean by "dedicated channel"?

Comment: Ever been to a conference?

Comment: On the topic of the university e-mail: I had thought about it, but i wanted to check if there was a better channel first (when i talked about my personal e-mail i was actually talking about my university e-mail, sorry for the confusion, i'll update the OP). I have consulted my thesis advisors extensively, but they don't have experience in dealing with this kind of situations. In any case, thanks a lot for your time, i'll keep trying.

Comment: Email seems to be the way to go, at least if I go by all the unsolicited "please participate in my study on XYZ in academia"-mails every address posted on some official webpage seems to get. In other words, try it but be warned that many recipients will treat such mails as spam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing the comments: the primary form of communication and dissemination of information among academics is e-mail, for better or worse.  But perhaps more towards what your end goal might be, a Slack channel might be appropriate.  You will still need to solicit participants via e-mail and advertising on ResearchGate or listservs dedicated to your research field.  But once you get a core group, you can put everyone on Slack and give them admin permissions to add additional participants as the group grows.

Comment: I don't think anyone would join a Slack group dedicated to this ... plus then you would be selecting against everyone who doesn't use Slack (which is probably the majority of academics), which is most likely not representative of whatever group you're trying to measure.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I will consider this option too.

Comment: @AzorAhai I know a number of European academics who use Slack, especially at research institutes.  Maybe it's more popular among comp-sci folk, but tools like this are incredibly useful for organizing big projects with lots of players.

Comment: I know a number too and use it myself. Still don't think it's anywhere near the majority